# ExpressJs - dbQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In console, when I go to specific item id I have error(ExpressJs):

```
ReferenceError: dbQuery is not defined
```

My api.js

```
    var express = require('express'),
    Bourne = require('bourne'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),

    db = new Bourne('data.json'),
    router = express.Router();
....
    .route('/contact/:id')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            db.findOne(req,dbQuery, function (err, data) { //problem
                res.json(data);
            });
        })
 ....

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where is dbQuery being defined?  If its coming from a form it needs to be `req.body.dbQuery` or `req.query.dbQuery`.

Comment: Thanks :) I must only add req.dbQuery (I forgot dot)

Answer (score 0):

`dbQuery` is not defined? If its coming from a form it needs to be `req.body.dbQuery` or `req.query.dbQuery`.

If set somewhere else, `req.dbQuery` needs to be a dot not a comma.